# (invoke@invoke.c:331 errno: None) run_dotnet(dotnet_path, &args) failed

Tags: c#, .net-core, serialization, lambda, json.net

Hello guys I need your help, I am using AWS Lambda (.NET Core) to serializing some List to JSON string (Newtonsoft)

So the problem is when rows are 500 it works fine but when it exceeds to 1000, 2000 method gets crash and throw following exception

```
**[WARN] (invoke@invoke.c:331 errno: None) run_dotnet(dotnet_path, &args) failed.**
```

List has basic properties like Firstname, lastname, company, email, contact no. etc and AWS Lambda has 1024 MB RAM.

Initially I thought Newtonsoft is consuming a lots of memory for serialization so I increase the Ram with 2024MB but I am facing the same exception.

I know that above exception is something related to memory.

So according to you what is wrong with my lambda.

1. Is there any chance that Newtonsoft uses to much memory and it crash the method.
2. Is Newtonsoft.Json right way to perform serialization in Lambda or we should use Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson

I am using following syntax for serializtion.

```
_logger.Information($"Rows details {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_list)}");
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does `_logger.Information()` do?  Does it simply stream the incoming string to a file, or does it save the incoming string in memory?  Also, how long are the strings generated by `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_list)`?

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same error message and resolved it by increasing the memory of the lambda. To test, we choked the lambda down to 128mb of memory and consistently reproduced the error.